# MySQL table with composite primary key LIMIT 1 is very slow while Limit 2 is fast

Tags: mysql

I have `ProductInfo` table with following indexes -

```
Primary:  ProductCode, Model, Added_Date, id
Index: id
```

The composite primary key are the columns I use in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM ProductInfo WHERE 
ProductCode='45678' AND 
Model='PQA-1'  AND 
(Added_Date >='2021-08-01 00:00:00' AND Added_Date <='2021-08-14 23:59:59') 
ORDER BY Added_Date ASC;
```

This query works pretty fine

**Problem**

The following query is fast

```
select * from ProductInfo WHERE ProductCode="45678" order by id desc limit 1;
```

Here is the explain
[image]

But the following query is **very very slow**. Please note that query is same but just `ProductCode` is different

```
select * from ProductInfo WHERE ProductCode="78342" order by id desc limit 1;
```

Here is the explain.
[image]

However, same query with Limit 2 is fast

```
select * from ProductInfo WHERE ProductCode="78342" order by id desc limit 2;
```

Here is the explain
[image]

What is the cause? Is my indexing correct? What will be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Renew statistic then test again.

Comment: @Akina how do I do that? How long does it take if DB is very large?

Comment: I think this is caused by choosing the wrong indexes. A good PRIMARY index would be `id`. You could keep your composite index, if it is useful somewhere, but as a normal index. Note that the query you say you use it for doesn't need `id` to be part of the composite index. Start by making indexes on individual field like `ProductCode` and `Added_Date`, and then experiment with composite indexes to see if you can speed up certain queries.

Comment: *how do I do that?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE ProductInfo; for us to consider your table design.  And B) SHOW INDEX FROM ProductInfo; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'ProductInfo';  to consider more aspects of your table.

Answer (score 1):

The first query benefits from this index:

```
PRIMARY KEY(ProductCode, Model, Added_Date)
```

All the other queries could not fully benefit from either of your indexes.  The Optimizer guessed at one index in one case; the other index in the other.  This would work well for both cases:

```
INDEX(ProductCode, Id)
```

One reason for the timing differences is the distribution of data in the table.  Your examples *may not* show the same timings if you change the `78342` to some other value.

The new index I recommend will make those queries "fast" regardless of the ProductCode searched on.  And "Rows" will say "1" or "2" instead of about "25000".

It sounds like there are about 25K rows with `ProductCode = 78342`.